# 「質問を送信できませんでした。投稿する前に1件の問題を解決して下さい」と出る

Tags: サポート, 質問の仕方

新しい質問をしようとしても
質問を送信できませんでした。
投稿する前に1件の問題を解決して下さい
とでます。

前の質問の中の回答のチェックマークをクリックして緑色表示にさせた(ベストアンサー)は選んだはずなのですがそれでもだめでした。
どなたか解決方法教えてくれませんか？

(票がうまく投票されていないからでしょうか？)

↓リンクです
[Javaの問題を教えて下さい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/81117/java%e3%81%ae%e5%95%8f%e9%a1%8c%e3%82%92%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%95%e3%81%84/82432?noredirect=1#comment93211_82432)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: こちらは既存の質問についてのエラーではなくて、今投稿なさろうとしている質問についてのエラーに見えます。もし可能であれば [edit] してエラー画面のスクリーンショットを添付いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 既存の質問の画面ではなくて、新しい質問を投稿してエラーが出た瞬間の画面があると嬉しいです。おそらく新しく投稿なさろうとしている質問の内容が何かしらの条件でエラーを引き起こしています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

エラー時点での情報が少ないので断言はできませんが、おそらく投稿しようとしていた質問側に問題があったのだと思います。

質問投稿時にはその質問が問題なく書けているのかチェックする仕組みがあり、いくつかの部分について自動判定が行われています。そのどれかにひっかかるとエラーと修正すべき点が表示されるはずなので、それにしたがって修正を行ってみてください。